# sscanf() has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-excel

I use [laravel-excel](https://laravel-excel.com/) for export data in laravel and it's ok in my local, but when I deploy the project to a shared host I get this error:

> "message": "sscanf() has been disabled for security reasons",
>
> "exception": "ErrorException",
>
> "file":
> "/path/to/project/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Collection/Cells.php",

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your php configuration file, remove sscanf from the disable_functions.

Comment: Do you mean in php.ini file? if so is already removed but still, i get the same error

Comment: try use  php -c /path/to/php.ini to specify it